# Python Unit Testing: Want to Find Out How a Method Was Called Without Changing the Method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm writing a unit test in Python for something that looks like this:

```
def code_to_test(x):
  #gets an instance of MyClass
  #does some stuff...

  (x,y,z) = my_class_instance.some_method(a,b)

  #other stuff happens with x, y, and z that I don't care about
```

All I want to do is find out how some_method got called. I DON'T want to change the return value.

But when I:

```
with mock.patch.object(module.MyClass, 'some_method') as mock_method:
  code_to_test(7)
```

I get need more than 0 values to unpack because that method returns a tuple. So if I don't want to specify the return value, it assumes None?

Should I even be mocking `some_method` if I don't care about the return value? Is there some way to just find out if it was called? How can I write a test so that the stuff after the method invokation can run with correct values of x,y,z?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Mock` around the original method, so that when the mock is called, it calls the actual value and returns its return value.

```
with mock.patch.object(module.MyClass,
                       'some_method',
                       wraps=module.MyClass.some_method) as mock_method:
    code_to_test(7)
```

Comment: Yes, this would be easy if I could just call the method and get a return value, but it's an instance method:
TypeError: unbound method some_method() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)

I'm surprised there isn't a way to just passively monitor what's going on instead of replacing the method.

Comment: Can you patch `my_class_instance` instead of `module.MyClass`?